# Maven enforcer doesn't detect AdoptOpenJDK-11

Tags: java, maven, jhipster

I have a jhipster project. I run

```
sudo mvn clean install -U
```

(Without sudo, it fails, saying it can't delete some files).

I get output

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-versions) @ jhipProj ---
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
You are running an incompatible version of Java. JHipster supports JDK 8 to 14.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.125 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-04T15:10:54-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-versions) on project jhipProj: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
```

I run the command to see what it's getting for java

```
>> java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)
>>mvn enforcer:display-info
[INFO] Maven Version: 3.8.2
[INFO] JDK Version: 11.0.11 normalized as: 11.0.11
[INFO] OS Info: Arch: x86_64 Family: mac Name: mac os x Version: 10.15.7
```

Why on earth is my maven build failing, and what freaking java version is it trying to pick up?? Clearly I'm running 11, which is between 8 and 14.

Comment: Sudo is a bad habit. Files end up being owned by root and then you can’t delete them.  Reconsider this.

Comment: Also update maven-enforcer-plugin version to most recent. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: Can you please check via `mvn --version`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this command :
mvn --version

Check the JAVA_HOME path in your environment variables.

Set JAVA_HOME to the path of the new java version